# MVC5 ModelView is not valid on post of edit action

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have an MVC5 project with Entity 6 framework and I am having trouble getting the correct information passed to the edit action on the post, in order to bind it to the models. The ModelState of my viewModel comes back as invalid.  I am not sure what I am missing. I am guessing that it has to do with the way that my Editor templates are setup vs the structure of my models but I need some help figuring it out. I have spent many hours changing things to try and get this working and I still cant get it corrected.

My ViewModel:

```
namespace CommunityHealth.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ActivityViewModel
    {
        public virtual IList<JunctionTypeAction> junctionTypeActions{ get; set; }
        public virtual IList<JunctionDepartmentAction> junctionDepartmentActions{ get; set; }
        public virtual IList<JunctionPopulationAction> junctionPopulationActions { get; set; }
        public virtual CommunityAction Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Community Action Model:

```
public partial class CommunityAction
{
    public CommunityAction()
    {
        this.JunctionPopulationActions = new HashSet<JunctionPopulationAction>();
        this.JunctionDepartmentActions = new HashSet<JunctionDepartmentAction>();
        this.JunctionTypeActions = new HashSet<JunctionTypeAction>();
    }

    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public string BreifDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string SubLocation { get; set; }
    public int ProgramID { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public byte[] RecordVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JunctionPopulationAction> JunctionPopulationActions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JunctionDepartmentAction> JunctionDepartmentActions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JunctionTypeAction> JunctionTypeActions { get; set; }
}
```

The Models for the Junction Tables:
JunctionDepartmentAction:

```
public partial class JunctionDepartmentAction
{
    public int IndexID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public string SubDepartment { get; set; }
    public int Individuals { get; set; }

    public virtual CommunityAction CommunityAction { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

JunctionPopulationAction:

```
public partial class JunctionPopulationAction
{
    public int IndexID { get; set; }
    public int PopulationID { get; set; }
    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public virtual CommunityAction CommunityAction { get; set; }
    public virtual TargetPopulation TargetPopulation { get; set; }
}
```

JunctionTypeAction:

```
public partial class JunctionTypeAction
{
    public int IndexID { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public virtual ActivityType ActivityType { get; set; }
    public virtual CommunityAction CommunityAction { get; set; }
}
```

Event Controller Edit Action Methods:

```
// GET: /Event/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        CommunityAction communityaction = await db.CommunityActions.FindAsync(id);
        ActivityViewModel activityviewmodel = new ActivityViewModel();
        activityviewmodel.Action = communityaction;
        IList<JunctionTypeAction> junctiontypeactions = await db.JunctionTypeActions.Where(d => d.ActionID == communityaction.ActionID).ToListAsync();
        IList<JunctionDepartmentAction> junctiondepartmentactions = await db.JunctionDepartmentActions.Where(d => d.ActionID == communityaction.ActionID).ToListAsync();
        IList<JunctionPopulationAction> junctionpopulationactions = await db.JunctionPopulationActions.Where(d => d.ActionID == communityaction.ActionID).ToListAsync();
        activityviewmodel.junctionTypeActions = junctiontypeactions.ToList();
        activityviewmodel.junctionDepartmentActions = junctiondepartmentactions.ToList();
        activityviewmodel.junctionPopulationActions = junctionpopulationactions.ToList();            
        if (communityaction == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", activityviewmodel.Action.LocationID);
        ViewBag.ProgramID = new SelectList(db.Programs, "ProgramID", "ProgramID", activityviewmodel.Action.ProgramID);
        return View(activityviewmodel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ActivityViewModel activity)
    {
        //request added for debugging purposes
        Request.ToString();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", activity.Action.LocationID);
        ViewBag.ProgramID = new SelectList(db.Programs, "ProgramID", "ProgramID", activity.Action.ProgramID);
        return View(activity);
    }
```

And finally my Views. I am using three editor templates for the junction tables in the DataBase and one more for the CommunityAction object. I then have a view for the event that uses the three editor templates to display the parts of the ViewModel.

CommunityAction.cshtml:

```
@model CommunityHealth.Models.CommunityAction
<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>CommunityAction</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActionID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RecordVersion)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BreifDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BreifDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BreifDescription)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Duration, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Duration)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Duration)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationID, "Location", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Location, ViewBag.LocationID as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "control-form" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubLocation, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubLocation)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubLocation)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgramID, "Program", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProgramID, ViewBag.ProgramID as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "control-form" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Program)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddedBy, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddedBy)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddedBy)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
    </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

JunctionTypeAction.cshtml:

```
@model CommunityHealth.Models.JunctionTypeAction
<div class="type">
<fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActionID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IndexID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TypeID, "TypeName", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
</fieldset>
</div>
```

JunctionDepartmentAction.cshtml:

```
@model CommunityHealth.Models.JunctionDepartmentAction
@using CommunityHealth.Models
<div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActionID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IndexID)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentID, "DepartmentName", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubDepartment, "SubDepartment", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 " })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Individuals)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JunctionPopulationAction.cshtml:

```
@model CommunityHealth.Models.JunctionPopulationAction

<div class="population">
<fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActionID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IndexID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PopulationID, "PopulationName", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Views\Event\Edit.cshtml:

```
@model CommunityHealth.Models.ViewModels.ActivityViewModel
@using CommunityHealth.Models.ViewModels;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Event",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Action)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Types")
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <fieldset>
                    @for (int x = 0; x < Model.junctionTypeActions.Count(); x++)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.junctionTypeActions[x])
                    }
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Departments")
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int x = 0; x < Model.junctionDepartmentActions.Count(); x++)
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.junctionDepartmentActions[x])
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Target Populations")
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int x = 0; x < Model.junctionDepartmentActions.Count(); x++)
                {
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.junctionPopulationActions[x])
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I am getting this error when I examine the request:

> "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'CommunityHealth.Models.CommunityAction' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

Comment: What is the issue on postback - is the model null? are properties of the model null? are the collections not being bound? (do you really expect anyone to wade through all that code) Note: Rendering all those hidden inputs is bad practice and degrades performance - use view models to represent only what you want to edit. And just use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.junctionTypeActions)` - not inside a `for` loop

Comment: I appreciate any feedback. I certainly don't 'expect' anybody to help, I was simply hoping that somebody might take a look and see what it is that I am missing. If somebody does choose to look into my issue, I want them to have everything that they need to figure out what I have done wrong.  I didn't plan on keeping the hidden types. I do like the way you have the junctions and have changed to this for simplicities sake.

Comment: Your models shouldn't be this complex... Heck, why are the collections virtual?  This is not Entity Framework.  There's typically no reason to have all those collections referencing each other in a view model.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch These models were all generated by Entity framework 6 Data Entity Model, except for the view model that I created? The models are not that complex.  There are three models for the SQL junction tables that hold the many to many relationship data, and the model for the CommunityAction which is also an SQL table.  The virtual properties are there to hold the relationships with the foreign keys. The hash sets are there to do lookup of the related items in the junction tables.  This is all makes sense, so I am not sure what would be wrong with the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that error is because you model has a property named `activity` (typeof `CommunityAction`), and the parameter of your post method is also named `activity`. Change the parameter name to anything other than the name of a property in the model(s)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ActivityViewModel model)
{
  ....
}
```

Side notes

1. Simply use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.junctionTypeActions)` to generate
   the html for collections (not in a `for` loop). `@Html.EditorFor()`
   is smart enough to recognize collections and generate the correct
   html.
2. Generating all those hidden inputs is bad practice and degrades
   performance (and any malicious user could change the values anyway).
   Use view models for each or your types that contain only the
   properties you need to display/edit.

Comment: This seems to have gotten me past the current roadblock!  I had to change my CommunityAction editor template so that it was bound to LocationID instead of Location, but this was easy to find once I changed the name and was able to properly view all of my results at my breakpoint.  Thank you for your help!